# Download of data in template xls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xls

I wanted to know how to redirect to a template, and make it download with this template, I tried some things, using the template I had in pdf, but it is not working.
Here is how far I've been:

```
def download
    @reversals = Reversal.where("created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?", params[:start_date], params[:end_date])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xls {           
           send_data(:filename => 'estornos.xls', :disposition => 'attachment', :action => :index, :layout => false, :template => 'reversals/download.xls.erb', locals: {:reversals => @reversals})
        }
    end
 end
```

here I call in my view:

```
<%= form_for :reversal, method: :post, url: download_reversals_path do %>
        <%= date_select "reversal", "start_date" %>
        <%= date_select "reversal", "end_date" %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Download' %>
<% end %>
```

here is my route:

```
resources :reversals do
    collection do
      post 'download', :defaults => { :format => 'xls', :template => 'download.xls.erb'}
    end
  end
```

I have already put the type of xls in the mime_type. I already mounted the template, but I can not connect the two. The template with the method, they have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests and time I found how to do:

routes:

```
post 'reversals/download', to: "reversals#download_pdf", as: 'download', format: 'xls'
```

controller:

```
def download_pdf
    report_start_date= build_date_from_params("start_date", params[:reversal])
    report_end_date= build_date_from_params("end_date", params[:reversal])
    @reversals = Reversal.all.where("created_at >= ? and created_at <= ? or created_at = ? and created_at = ? ", report_start_date, report_end_date, report_start_date, report_end_date)
    @start_date = report_start_date
    @end_date = report_end_date
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xls {
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=" estornos-' + (Time.now).to_s + '.xls"'
        render "download.xls.erb"
       }
    end
end
def build_date_from_params(field_name, params)
      Date.new(params["#{field_name.to_s}(1i)"].to_i, 
           params["#{field_name.to_s}(2i)"].to_i, 
           params["#{field_name.to_s}(3i)"].to_i)
end
```

mime_types:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls
```

in my index view

```
<%= form_for :reversal, method: :post, url: download_path, format: 'xlsx' do %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>DATA DE LANÇAMENTO INICIAL:</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><%= date_select "reversal", "start_date" %></td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center"><%= submit_tag 'Download xlsx', class: 'btn btn-secundary' %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DATA DE LANÇAMENTO FINAL:</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><%= date_select "reversal", "end_date" %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

If you are trying to download to excel, the format xls does not work, it has to be xlsx, it is only to register in the mime types the xlsx format, and in the view pass in the format: xlsx, in the routes tb create or change the one that is with the format: xlsx. Do not forget to create a view with nameoffunction.xlsx.erb.